# Array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to c# and just practicing with object arrays. tried to display the elements of the array using loop but this code didn't display anything. Please help

```
using System;
using System.Text;
   
namespace pra
{
    class program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
      
        person[] person1 = new person[2];

        person1[0] = new person("Mike");
        person1[1] = new person("John");

        for (int i =0; i < person1.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}",person1[i].Name);
        }
    }


    
}
class person
{
    string name;
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public person(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your `person` class has a private member `name` which you set in the constructor and a public auto-implemented property `Name` which you don't set - and you try to print the property which is not set

Comment: Your class Person doesn't return anything when you call Name property.

Comment: Since you are learning, ... Consider learning the naming conventions.  If you were clearer on the naming and capitalization, the error might have been more apparent.  Also, did you put breakpoints in your code and step through it?  The debugger is great at making errors visible

Answer (score 3):

You're setting a value to the `name` field (which is never read), then reading from the `Name` property (which was never set).

You don't need (or want) both of them here.  Remove the field and just use the property:

```
class person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to make it work is to change your Person class

```
class person
{
    string name;
    public string Name { get=>name; set=>name=value; }
    public person(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the field `name` and an auto property `Name` at the same time. If you store the value in `name` it, won't be accessible by the property `Name`, unless you write a getter and a setter to do so. But with C# you can skip all that and just use an auto property with a hidden backing field.

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

You can also simplify the conversion between `Person` and `string` by overriding the `ToString()` method. See example usage below:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      
        Person[] array= new Person[2];

        array[0] = new Person("Mike");
        array[1] = new Person("John");

        for (int i =0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice that the `WriteLine()` statement will display each person's Name`property because that is what the`ToString()` method instructs it to do. Control of what and how it is displayed is in the class and not with the program.

PS. Also, note that class names and types should be capitalized in order to distinguish them from fields and variables. Properties also should be capitalized.